# Minecraft Connection Errors

Tags: minecraft

This is probably on the wrong site, so go ahead and move it if you have to... but I have been getting this same problem for the past week and it's really starting to irritate me.  When I try to join my friend's MC server, I get an error saying "Disconnected Took too long to login."  I googled the error and found that it could possibly be because the minecraft member authentication servers are down, but I eliminated that possibility by having my friend login to my account.  It worked fine for him with the same server.

I also thought that maybe my minecraft client wasn't up to date with the server,  so I tried updating my client with the update that the server used(12w07a) but that didn't change anything.

Then, I tried the idea to port forward my router to 25565, but that didn't do anything.  My friend said sometimes ISP's(mine is verizon fios) block certain ports from being forwarded.  If that's the case, is there any way of getting around it?

So I am not sure  what exactly is causing the problem.  Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your connection worked fine before this past week, it wouldn't make sense that Verizon is suddenly blocking certain ports. More than likely, there are some odd network settings floating around in your computer. If you're not sure if port 25565 is the correct port to forward, you can Enable DMZ (if your router supports it), which is basically forwarding ALL your ports (be sure to set it to your correct LAN IP, which can be found by command-prompting 'ipconfig'). If you have no software firewalls turned on, and you have enabled DMZ, there really shouldn't be any more networking issues...

Comment: This was necro'd, but for the sake of correct information: only the MC server needs to forward ports for _inbound traffic_ (i.e. connecting players). If the server is on your friend's local connection, they likely are able to connect because they don't need to forward to access it, but you will need that forwarding (on _their_ network). The authentication is performed server-side w/ Mojang; you were already able to log in, so that's not the issue.